# What is the impact of inlining a jpg data into code instead of loading it as external resource

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, mach-o

For various reasons which I don't want to get into, it is very convenient for me to inline the data of a JPG into the source code.

So rather than loading the image through the regular APIs such as `[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.jpg"]` I would like to convert the JPG into base64 string and then load it like:

```
+(NSString *)error_1 {
  return @"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";
}
+(UIImage *)img_error_1 {
  NSData *d = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:[self error_1] options:0];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:d];
}
```

I understand that this is probably a horrible thing to do and that I am a horrible person, this is a code smell etc. etc. but for distribution purposes of my SDK it is very simple.

What is interesting to me is how this impacts the memory / binary size of the SDK and if it is problematic in other forms.

I tried several trivial tests like comparing the binary size but didn't find that it increased in a drastic way. I also tried profiling the memory of it but couldn't get to a concrete answer (Also with blank projects containing only the image data or only the jpg)

Is there any literature on this?

Comment: `UIImage` caches images loaded through `imageNamed:`, but that doesn't mean they are never released.

Comment: not sure what that has to do with the problem. I mean what is the impact in general of bloating the binary

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring whether this is good or bad, your concern is over the possible increase in size. Well Base64 encoding does increase the byte size by 33% compared to the raw bytes. There will be additional increase as you are storing the Base64 characters as an `NSString` and not as an 8-bit character string. Taking both into account every three bytes of image data could end up being around 8 bytes.

An alternative way of doing the same thing which should save you some storage would be to use a statically initialised `Byte` array, something like:

```
static Byte imageData[] = { ... };
```

declared as the global level (using `static` to stop the identifier being available outside of the current compilation unit).

To get the bytes to fill in the `...` you can use the `hexdump` command in the Terminal:

```
hexdump -v -e '16/1 "0x%02x, " "\n"' <myImage.jpg >myDump.txt
```

This produces 16 bytes per line, in hex literal format, comma seperated. You can then paste (or `#include`) the contents of `myDump.txt` into your code. The `hexdump` will NUL pad the dump to be a multiple of 16, so you should check the size of `myImage.jpg` and delete the redundant `0x0`'s at the end.

You can produce an `NSData` from this *without* copying the memory at all:

```
NSData *d = [[NSdata alloc] dataWithBytesNoCopy:imageData 
                                         length:sizeof(imageData)
                                   freeWhenDone:NO];
```

and from that continue as before.

HTH